# How to filter some data from a dataframe over other dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have two dataframe (df1 and df2) that has in common the id, df1 has many columns and thousands of rows and df2 has just the id and an operation in another column, all I need is to filter the ids from the df2 in df1 resulting as a new dataframe (df3) mantaining all the columns from df1 considereing too that the ids in df2 are not necessarily in df1.

df1:

```
| id       | zone |category|status  |
|----------|------|--------|--------|
| M3RR9000 | I    | x      |on track|
| M3RR9012 | II   | c      |finished|
| M3RR9020 |V     | v      |on track|
```

df2

```
| id       | value|
|----------|------|
| M3RR9000 | 3    |
```

df3

```
| id       | zone |category|status  |
|----------|------|--------|--------|
| M3RR9000 | I    | x      |on track|
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` works:

```
df3 = df1 %>% filter(id %in% df2$id)
```